# NerdTREE in VSCODE

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

In VIM there is a pluggin called NerdTREE that is to move between folders, I am looking for something similar for vscode, where I can move between files but with the keyboard.

Comment: Keep using Vim :D

Comment: @Enlico I use Vim but at school the teachers want me to use vscode. What I did was to install a vim plugin in vscode to simulate that it is vim but I wanted to navigate between files and folders like in Vim.

Comment: Did you try [neovim](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=asvetliakov.vscode-neovim)?

Comment: @ikhvjs No, I just only use vim. Do yo recommend me neovim?

Comment: It looks like it support to install plugin and you may install NerdTree from it after you install this VScode extension. It is similar to Vim.

Answer (score 0):

As I write this, there is an extension available in VSCode with the same name you mention.

This recently released extension has only basic commands such as creating folders and files, moving between them, copying, pasting, renaming or opening a file.

Well, it also has very few configuration options so maybe that is discouraging, but in short I consider it a good alternative for the moment to have some of that vim pluggin, and maybe over time the developer will add new features.

Here is the repository of this extension so you can take a look at it: https://github.com/61130061/NERDTree